# "If everyone who speaks Chinese also speaks English and at least one person does not speak English, then somebody does not speak Chinese."

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

> If everyone who speaks Chinese also speaks English and at least one person does not speak English, then somebody does not speak Chinese.

Let C(x) and E(x) denote "x speaks Chinese" and "x speaks English", respectively.

Is my translation correct?

$$\forall x~\Big[\exists y~\big[ (C(x) \to E(x)) \land \lnot E(y)\big]\Big] \to \exists x~\big[\lnot C(x)\big]$$

Could you explain if the sentence is valid? (I think it is.) I dont need the proof.

Comment: Yes that is correct though personally I would put the $\exists y$ right with the $\neg E(y)$ ... I think that's just a little more readable.

Comment: Could you explain if it is valid? Because I think it is. I dont need the proof

Comment: @augusras yes, it is valid. Consider one of the people that do not speak English. Well, if this person would speak Chinese, then this person would speak English, but this person does not speak English, and so does not speak Chinese either. So, there is at least one person that does not speak Chinese

Answer (score 1):

> "If everyone who speaks Chinese also speaks English and at least one person does not speak English, then somebody does not speak Chinese."

A more direct formalisation than yours (they are equivalent):  $$\Big(\forall x~\big( Cx \to Ex\big) ~\land~ \exists y~\lnot Ey\Big) \to \exists z~ \lnot Cz.$$

> Could you explain if it is valid? I dont need the proof.

The given sentence corresponds to a valid categorical-logic argument about the universe of animals:

- premise 1: Every cat is egotistical.
- premise 2: Some animal is not egotistical.
- conclusion: Some animal is not a cat.